# Bot Framework openUrl not working for suggested action on messenger

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, facebook-messenger

I am creating facebook bot using Bot Builder Node.js sdk and I am trying to create suggested action, which would navigate users to web page. I know, that facebook has limitation, that it redirects only to https endpoints, but as the the page I am redirecting to is https, this is clearly not a problem. Here is my code:

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
.text("User message here")
.suggestedActions(
    builder.SuggestedActions.create(
            session, [
                builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "command1", "Command1"),
                builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "command2", "Command2"),
                builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, "https url", "Go to web")
            ]
        )); 
session.send(msg);
```

Problem is, that when I click the openUrl action on messenger, nothing happens. It works properly on emulator. Please, can somebody help me, how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: I ended up using HeroCard. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. HeroCard was way to go also for me. Apparently messenger does not support openUrl in action buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook messenger suggested actions (Quick Reply) do not support "openURL".
Quick Replies only support the [following](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies/):

- Text Quick Reply: Text will be shown to user, payload will be send back to bot
- Phone Number Quick Reply:

> allows you to ask a user for the phone number. When the phone number quick reply is sent, the Messenger Platform will automatically pre-fill the displayed quick reply with the phone number from the user's profile information.

- Email Quick Reply:

> allows you to ask a user for the email. When the email quick reply is sent, the Messenger Platform will automatically pre-fill the displayed quick reply with the email from the user's profile information.

- Location Quick Reply **(Deprecated)**