# Microsoft bot framework openurl not working for SuggestedActions in messagener

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-chatbot

```
var resultMessage = context.MakeMessage();resultMessage.SuggestedActions = new 
SuggestedActions(){Actions = new List<CardAction>(){new 
CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Book now", value: "http url"),}}; await 
context.PostAsync(resultMessage);
```

When I am clicking on this 'Book Now' button its not redirecting to url in FB messenger

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it is an issue as the issue is reported on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3147) and also in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081848/bot-framework-openurl-not-working-for-suggested-action-on-messenger). Maybe you can use a herocard instead of suggested action.

Comment: but our requirement is use suggested action.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at [Facebook quick replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies) and it seems it is not possible to open a URL from those as well, so this leads me to believe that it will not be possible to open a URL with suggested actions on the Facebook platform either.  In addition to rich cards mentioned above, you can also send links in the text generally in markdown for most channels.  I will double check with the team and confirm that this is not possible on Facebook and update this answer if I find out differently.

We are now tracking this internally and will look into making it possible, no timeline to report at this time.